# Filter or find items by part number

Tags: ebay-api

I'm trying to find the cheapest results for specific part numbers, however I cannot for the life of me figure out how to search by part number. Ebay has this data in the "item specifics" section as you can see [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-COMPLETE-IGNITION-DISTRIBUTOR-FITS-2-2L-4cyl-5SFE-/170721624197?pt=Motors_Car_Truck_Parts_Accessories&hash=item27bfcd4085&vxp=mtr), if you scroll down.

I've been reading the API docs but there doesn't seem to be any call that allows you to search by item specifics. Does anyone know a way to do this?